# What is the correct way of calculating the sphere volume with radius 1?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Given the following integration limits $\int^1_0\int^{2\pi}_0\int^{\pi}_0$

If I calculate $\int^1_0\int^{2\pi}_0\int^{\pi}_0 r^2r^2\sin(\phi) \,d\phi\,d\theta\, dr$

It gives the wrong sphere volume with radius 1: $4\pi/5$

If I calculate $\int^1_0\int^{2\pi}_0\int^{\pi}_0 r^2\sin(\phi)\, d\phi\,d \theta\, dr$

It gives the correct sphere volume with radius 1: $4\pi/3$

Why is that? What is the correct way of calculating the sphere volume with radius 1?

Comment: Where does your $r^2r^2$ come from?

Comment: The Jacobian is $r^2 \sin{\phi}$ and you shouldn't integrate $r^2$ but instead $1$.

Comment: but shouldn't I integrate $x^2+y^2+z^2$, i.e., $r^2$?

Comment: $\iiint_R dxdydz$ is the volume-form.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is $$\int^1_0\int^{2\pi}_0\int^{\pi}_0 r^2\sin(\phi)\, d\phi\,d \theta\, dr$$

as you have figured out. In order to find the volume of an object with triple integral ,  all you need is $$v=\int \int\int _{E} dv$$

In your case $$dv=r^2\sin(\phi)\, d\phi\,d \theta\, dr$$ so there is no need for an extra $r^2$

Of course you know that an easier way to find the volume of a sphere is to use either disc method or shell method with a single integral.